# Is there a drupal.org API for retrieving the list of available modules?

Tags: community-official-site

Is there a drupal.org API for retrieving the list of available modules, a description of them and available versions?

Comment: Call `modules` to `projects` is a common mistake. Projects are compound of modules (or themes, or install profiles,...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very recently there's an API published: https://www.drupal.org/api

Answer (score 1):

There is no such API or mechanism at this time.

There is talk about extending Drush to support a Search functionality:
https://drupal.org/node/1389460

But that's after a database of dependencies is created for all modules and stored in a binary-ish form fetchable by Drush:
https://drupal.org/node/1299332

Comment: Can't help but mention that I made a really simple drush search extension: https://drupal.org/sandbox/Letharion/1833420

Comment: changed the answer to the one just submitted by pcambra as it the up to date one now..

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there is a big machine-readable list of Drupal projects available here:

http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/project-list/all

Warning: Very large. :-)

Courtesy of this comment, which also tells you a URL pattern to crawl for release information: https://groups.drupal.org/node/65023#comment-204808

I wish there were good documentation about the availability of other such easter eggs.

Answer (score 1):

There's an issue to [Expose list of projects to external services (via JSON, XML, etc)](https://drupal.org/node/669910). That issue ended up providing a `tsv` file with a list of all stable releases (no -dev) for all projects in drupal.org. The list is generated each 4 hours, after http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/project-list/all is regenerated.

https://drupal.org/files/releases.tsv (~4MB)

The rationale for this file is in comment #88 if the linked issue.