# Can I download all data from drupal.org?

Tags: community-official-site

Does drupal.org make any data dumps available for the content it hosts? I would love a full dump of module / theme / distribution data, etc. without having to scrape the site.

Comment: Question 0: Why ?

Comment: @Ayesh K: I'm working on a way to quickly check if the modules you are using have been upgraded for Drupal 8. Currently I am scraping drupal.org for this but a proper data source would be nicer. http://drupal.balaclark.com / https://github.com/balaclark/workswithdrupal

Comment: http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/project-list/all is an XML document I've used for similar purposes. Takes a _long_ time to load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/project-list/all is a XML-document that lists all projects and their releases. It's a large file, but should provide all the info you need.

Comment: also see my other response to a similiar inquiry  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/105572/3279

Comment: Whilst not all site data is available here it still suits my needs very well for module data, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for?  ftp://ftp.drupal.org/

This dir seems to have all modules ftp://ftp.drupal.org/pub/drupal/files/projects/pub/drupal/files/projects/

Comment: That's not a folder, it's a zero-byte file...and I think you meant ftp://ftp.drupal.org/pub/drupal/files/projects

Comment: @Clive /pub/drupal/files/projects/pub/drupal/files/projects/   that is definitely a folder.   Also downloading all that crap via HTTP would be a real pain in the ass,  I definitely meant ftp://

Comment: Sorry, auto correct on my phone, the protocol was still supposed to be FTP the path just changed (it looks like you've doubled up on the path). My FTP client (nor chrome/safari) can resolve the URL in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find all downloadable files from drupal.org, but the page took about 5 minutes to load (I have a bad internet connection, but still, looks really long to load): http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you actually want to "know" the version information, well, then you have an API!

For drupal.org-hosted modules, the URL is: `http://updates.drupal.org/release-history`

If you want to check if a module is available, query in the following pattern:

```
http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/{project}/{major-version}/
```

- Views module example: `http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/views/8.x/`
- follow module (no 8.x): `http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/follow/8.x/`

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't help in getting the complete list of available modules but is still pretty useful for getting info on single modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain a list of **stable** releases in this file: https://drupal.org/files/releases.tsv (~4MB).

See my response here for details: [Is there a drupal.org API for retrieving the list of available modules?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/105571/is-there-a-drupal-org-api-for-retrieving-the-list-of-available-modules)