# How to identify all modules hosted on drupal.org that depend on a given module?

Tags: community-official-site

Assume any contributed module X (e.g [Quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz)) on [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/) (=D.O), or any of its sub-modules Y (e.g [Quiz Stats](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/quiz/tree/modules/quiz_stats)). Any such (sub-)module may depend on one or more other contributed (sub-)modules Z (e.g [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts), disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer), as indicated in the (sub-)module's info file (e.g in the last line of the [info file of the Quiz Stats](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/quiz/tree/modules/quiz_stats/quiz_stats.info) module).

**My question**: How can I identify all modules X and submodules Y, which depend on module Z?

The question about "[Is there a drupal.org API for retrieving the list of available modules?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/105571/39516)" is somehow related (not a duplicate IMO), but none of the answers there seem to help to find the answer to my question, or am I missing something in those answers?

**Note**: this question is really about modules "on drupal.org", so I may not even have Drupal installed anywhere ... Think of this question in the context of, for example, a [d8rules](http://d8rules.org) campaign, where somebody wants to try to find other modules depending on [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to reach out to the module (co-)maintainers of those other modules (for whatever reason related to such campaign).

Comment: Pierre what is D.O?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer check the edit (link) to D.O. I added. Did I use an abbreviation that is not correct maybe? Something else? BTW, it's D.O., not D.A. (= Drupal Answers, i.e "here"). Make sense?

Comment: Unless the module is installed on your system, (local) Drupal does not know what module that is. (module requiring entity without it being installed state they need 'entity'. Once it is installed it is named 'Entity API'.) So Drupal cannot resolve this locally. Use drush, it will resolve the dependencies for you.

Comment: In that case, this is dependent on a database of dependencies: https://www.drupal.org/node/1299332 (found in the d.o API question). Since the issue is still open, I'd say no.

Comment: @Neograph734, interesting link, but an "active" D6 feature request doesn't look like it will become "fixed" any time soon (hoop doet leven ...). but apart from that, if I correctly understand that issue, it's about the other way around, ie to find modules such as Z, starting from X (or Y), While my question is starting from Z, what are the modules X (or Y). Please correct me if I don't interprete that right.

Comment: You can save and lookup either way, the order in which you save them controls the amount of data, so there is an optimum. But I am not going to speculate here. I suppose composer would be able to do this (packagist.org already does this for 'regular' packages.) So something might come eventually.

Comment: Hm, composer seems to potentialy become part of a possible answer in the future ... hoop doet leven ... merci! Oeps, 3 languages in a single phrase, sorry, but "you" will get it.

Comment: I don't think it can easily be done. There is no database of dependencies to query. Dependencies are based purely on the .info(.yml) files. I think you would have to build a crawler that goes from module to module, indexing the .info(.yml) files, and creating a database of the dependencies against which you could query.

Comment: Related: there is a thread at Drupal.org about "Drush command for listing config dependencies" https://www.drupal.org/node/2319193

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was mentioned above the solution could be parsing info files of all projects hosted on drupal.org. You can use this [small tool](https://github.com/Chi-teck/drupal-project-loader) to facilitate the process of obtaining the codebase of Drupal contributed projects.

Below is an example of searching dependencies for Quiz module.

```
drupal-project-loader -c 5 -b 7.x -d d7_modules -y &&
cd d7_modules && ag 'dependencies\[\] = quiz$' -G \.info$ |
sed 's/\/.*//;s/^/https:\/\/www.drupal.org\/project\//' | uniq | sort
```

The result:

```
https://www.drupal.org/project/certificate
https://www.drupal.org/project/certify
https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_cert_quiz
https://www.drupal.org/project/cloze
https://www.drupal.org/project/course
https://www.drupal.org/project/elms_features
https://www.drupal.org/project/grouping_question
https://www.drupal.org/project/image_target_question
https://www.drupal.org/project/kalvi_core
https://www.drupal.org/project/mark_word
https://www.drupal.org/project/og_quiz
https://www.drupal.org/project/opigno
https://www.drupal.org/project/opigno_pretest_app
https://www.drupal.org/project/opigno_quiz_app
https://www.drupal.org/project/opigno_quiz_import_app
https://www.drupal.org/project/qq_import
https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz
https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz_ddlines
https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz_drag_drop
https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz_evaluation
https://www.drupal.org/project/quizfileupload
https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz_h5p
https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz_progress
https://www.drupal.org/project/quizrubric
https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz_sentence_drop
https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz_share
https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz_userpoints
https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz_voice_answer
https://www.drupal.org/project/quizwebform
https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_mcq
https://www.drupal.org/project/tincanapi
```

Comment: Interesting, merci! Would you mind expanding your answer please to also include a similar result for the "charts" module? If you do, I'll mark your answer right away as accepted also ...

Comment: @pierre-vriens, it is two-step process.
First you download all Drupal 7 modules then search their info files using following regular expression 'dependencies\[\] = quiz$'.